# iText library exception throwing on adding blank Cell with space

Tags: java, itext

I tried to add a blank cell with space `(" ")` into my pdf file. i.e

```
 PdfPCell blankCell = ContentHandler.getNormalCell(" ", language,fontsize);
```

It throws this error

```
Message: java.lang.NullPointerException
         com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException: java.lang.NullPointerException
         at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfDocument.add(PdfDocument.java:727)
         at com.itextpdf.text.Document.add(Document.java:282)
```

Then i removed space from cell.. i.e

```
PdfPCell blankCell = ContentHandler.getNormalCell("", language,fontsize);
```

I resolved my issue this way but pdf is in bad beauty.

Can somebody help me out with, is there any solution available for this, apart from what i am doing

Edited:

```
public static PdfPCell getNormalCell(String string, String language, float size) throws DocumentException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Font f =  new Font();
    if(string!=null && !"".equals(string)){
        f = getFontForThisLanguage(language);
    }
    if(size==-1)  //Using a condition to make color RED as per need in view report
    {
    f.setColor(BaseColor.RED);
    }

    f.setSize(size);

    Chunk chunk = new Chunk(new String(string.getBytes(), "UTF-8"),f);

    PdfPCell pdfCell1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(string, f));
    pdfCell1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);

    return pdfCell1;

}
```

Comment: I have never seen this problem before. I am the original developer of iText and I have never seen the `getNormalCell()` method before. You should share more info if you want an answer to this question. Which version of iText are you using?

Comment: Not to get suprised, we have created our own method named getNormalCell will edit my post with more information.

Comment: my itext version is itextpdf-5.1.3 and i have updated getNormalCell method.

Comment: (1) The method you use has a `fontsize` parameter; the method you share, doesn't. (2) you test for `string == null`, but regardless of what this returns, you do `string.getBytes()` which might cause a `NullPointerException`. (3) you create a `chunk` object, but you never use that `chunk`. **Need I say more, or do you understand that you should throw your code away and start anew?**

Comment: It's my bad... i made mistake copying the method...i have updated acutal method... what's your take on this method.

Comment: It's still badly written. Fix the obvious errors first, then we can take a look if there's an actual iText problem.

Comment: Please also extend the stack trace to allow seeing in which call of your code the exception occurs.

Answer (score 1):

First the answer to your question: I have created an example called [CellMethod](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/tables/CellMethod) and I can perfectly add a `" "` to a `PdfPCell` without causing a `NullPointerException`. This is my code:

```
public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    document.open();
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
    table.addCell("Winansi");
    table.addCell(getNormalCell("Test", null, 12));
    table.addCell("Winansi");
    table.addCell(getNormalCell("Test", null, -12));
    table.addCell("Greek");
    table.addCell(getNormalCell("\u039d\u03cd\u03c6\u03b5\u03c2", "greek", 12));
    table.addCell("Czech");
    table.addCell(getNormalCell("\u010c,\u0106,\u0160,\u017d,\u0110", "czech", 12));
    table.addCell("Test");
    table.addCell(getNormalCell(" ", null, 12));
    table.addCell("Test");
    table.addCell(getNormalCell(" ", "greek", 12));
    table.addCell("Test");
    table.addCell(getNormalCell(" ", "czech", 12));
    document.add(table);
    document.close();
}

public static PdfPCell getNormalCell(String string, String language, float size)
        throws DocumentException, IOException {
    if(string != null && "".equals(string)){
        return new PdfPCell();
    }
    Font f  = getFontForThisLanguage(language);
    if(size < 0) {
        f.setColor(BaseColor.RED);
        size = -size;
    }
    f.setSize(size);
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(string, f));
    cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
    return cell;
}
public static Font getFontForThisLanguage(String language) {
    if ("czech".equals(language)) {
        return FontFactory.getFont(FONT, "Cp1250", true);
    }
    if ("greek".equals(language)) {
        return FontFactory.getFont(FONT, "Cp1253", true);
    }
    return FontFactory.getFont(FONT, null, true);
}
```

The resulting PDF can be found here: [cell_method.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/cell_method.pdf)

Now about the comments. It's as if you don't want to accept that your code is badly written. Instead, you claim that there's a problem with iText. It is a bad craftsman who blames his tools.

You did an attempt to improve your method, but let's take a look at your method and add some comments:

```
public static PdfPCell getNormalCell(String string, String language, float size)
    throws DocumentException, IOException {
    // The next line will create an instance of Helvetica, 12pt.
    Font f =  new Font();
    // I don't understand this check. Why is it important to check string here?
    if(string!=null && !"".equals(string)){
        // are you sure you didn't want to check if language is not null?
        f = getFontForThisLanguage(language);
        // we have no idea what getFontForThisLanguage is doing
        // what if language is null, does it throw an exception?
    }
    // This is ridiculous. See the next comment to find out why
    if(size==-1)  //Using a condition to make color RED as per need in view report
    {
    f.setColor(BaseColor.RED);
    }
    // In some situations, you are setting the font size to -1, that doesn't make sense
    f.setSize(size);
    // This line doesn't make sense either.
    // (1.) string should already be in unicode.
    //      why are you getting the bytes and creating a UTF-8 string?
    // (2.) why are you creating this chunk object? you never use it
    Chunk chunk = new Chunk(new String(string.getBytes(), "UTF-8"),f);
    // See: you're creating a Phrase with string, you don't use chunk!
    PdfPCell pdfCell1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(string, f));
    pdfCell1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
    return pdfCell1;
}
```

Please compare with my version of the method.